# Dynamically create ajax user control doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, asp.net-ajax

I have simple user control with include ajax control - CalendarExtender. This is code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
TagPrefix="cc1" 
%><br />
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" 
    TargetControlID="TextBox2">
    </cc1:CalendarExtender><br /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On Page_Load event for this control I have code - just show on label date from calendar:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = TextBox2.Text;
}
```

First, I try dynamically create this control in Page_Load event for my web form:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Controls_MySimpleControl datap = LoadControl("~/Controls/MySimpleControl.ascx") as 
  Controls_MySimpleControl;
  Panel1.Controls.Add(datap);
}
```

Above code doesn't work (user control has been added and page works, but choose date in calendar not appear in label ). But when I above code place in Page_Init event, everything is OK. Could you explain, why it works in Page_Init, and doesn't work in Page_Load. Maybe, I should dynamically create control in different way?

Comment: I don't have a specific answer on this, but I can tell you that my most recent foray into trying to dynamically add controls to a page is a viewstate nightmare. I ended up having all the controls "preloaded" on the page, with viewstate and visibility toggled rather than dynamically adding and removing them. Is the dynamic loading a requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only one scriptmanager per page.  Your control has it's own script manager for each instance of the user control getting ajax confused.